# Why is numpy's arange displayed with precision errors in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pycharm, numpy-ndarray

I am using PyCharm Professional with Python 3.7.4 64bit.

When I am evaluating the result of

```
np.arange(2, 4, 0.01)
```

it is displayed with precision erros (see image).

```
np.array([x / 100 for x in range(200, 400)])
```

displays as expected and without these errors.

Why are these errors occurring and how to prevent them?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without the pycharm complications:

```
In [284]: np.arange(2,2.1, 0.01)                                                
Out[284]: array([2.  , 2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.04, 2.05, 2.06, 2.07, 2.08, 2.09, 2.1 ])
In [285]: np.arange(2,2.1, 0.01).tolist()                                       
Out[285]: 
[2.0,
 2.01,
 2.0199999999999996,
 2.0299999999999994,
 2.039999999999999,
 2.049999999999999,
 2.0599999999999987,
 2.0699999999999985,
 2.0799999999999983,
 2.089999999999998,
 2.099999999999998]
```

Floating point is never 'exact'.  The third item is, within 'epsilon' equal to 2.02.  `Out[284]` shows the values rounded to a consistent size, `Out285]` is the Python list display, showing each element in its full float glory.

`np.arange` warns about float steps:

```
When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not
be consistent.  It is better to use `numpy.linspace` for these cases.
```

`linspace` handles the end value better, but still shows the floating point display limits:

```
In [287]: np.linspace(2,2.1,11)                                                 
Out[287]: array([2.  , 2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.04, 2.05, 2.06, 2.07, 2.08, 2.09, 2.1 ])
In [288]: np.linspace(2,2.1,11).tolist()                                        
Out[288]: 
[2.0,
 2.01,
 2.02,
 2.0300000000000002,
 2.04,
 2.05,
 2.06,
 2.0700000000000003,
 2.08,
 2.09,
 2.1]
```

---

An alternative to your list comprehension, is to scale an integer `arange`

```
In [291]: np.arange(200,210)/100                                                
Out[291]: array([2.  , 2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.04, 2.05, 2.06, 2.07, 2.08, 2.09])
```

Comment: Even by adding `.tolist()` to both of my initial statements, the result seems to be unchanged. `arange` still shows the inaccuracies, the array divided by 100 does not. Is this a displaying error or are the numbers in the latter set really spot on?

Comment: If you know what precision you are dealing with, you can use the `.round` method to create a rounded instance of `np.arange` or `np.linspace`. For my use case, `np.linspace(0, 1, 11).round(12)` was enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to a random systematic precision error at the point of nth precision. If we change the precision down, it will be fixed. One workaround would be to use np.round to desired precision.

```
ex : np.round(np.linspace(2,2.1,11).tolist(),3)
```